# gis web application selenium testing

Tags: google-maps, tooltip, gis

How i can get a mouse hover to the particular point in google maps.

In my project Mouse Hover to the particular point at particular industrial area .mouse hover to that point getting a tooltip how to do in pls help me I sent URL of my Project and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCcW3.png) also.[the tooltip for area](http://183.83.218.176/REGEN/viewer/aqua.html?resource=Library%3A%2F%2FREGEN%2FLAYOUT%2FREGEN3.ApplicationDefinition)

Comment: There are many similar questions, try and search for `selenium mouseover is:q` here on Stackoverflow. What programming language are you testing this with? Javascript?

Comment: Java with selenium webdriver